# Problems with refind on MBP

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, macosx, grub-efi, refind

I'm running ubuntu on my late 2013 MBPr and dumb decisions have me in a pickle. A while ago I had a triple boot system, but problems with OSX made me more reliant on Ubuntu, and recently I've been using it as my daily OS. A while ago I removed the Windows partition, and today I removed the OSX partition, since it was essentially unusable with how frequently it crashed. I'd read the only downside was it made getting firmware updates more difficult, and I was fine with that. I had been using refind to boot into Ubuntu, but I had wiped and restored the OSX partition a number of times without reinstalling refind to it, and it kept working, so I figured OSX wasn't integral to whatever refind is doing. But guess I was wrong.

First time I tried rebooting after deleting OSX partition, I got a black screen for 30 seconds, then a Windows 8 message popping up saying computer is unable to boot (again I'd uninstalled windows about a month and a half earlier). Using a live usb, I tried reinstalling refind on ubuntu, which has worked... sorta. Refind for some reason installed to the sdcard which I forgot was plugged in. So now in order to boot I need to hold alt to boot into the sdcard refind, and can continue from there.

None of this is a major problem, but seems a bit unstable. I was wondering what is telling the OSX firmware to try to boot windows, and how to instead point it to ubuntu, or just delete the windows ghost partition so that refind boots automatically

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you examine your disk to determine if you have a [hybrid MBR.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) This is most easily spotted with `gdisk`:

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present
```

This example shows a legal GPT with a conventional protective MBR. If the `MBR:` line reads `hybrid` instead of `protective`, you've got a hybrid MBR.

If you've got a hybrid MBR, as I suspect you do, your disk is basically in a precariously-balanced state that might be causing at least some of your problems. Thus, you've got two choices of what to do. (You can do either of these things even if you've got a protective MBR, but in that case option #1 will be simpler.)

### Option #1: EFI-mode booting

You can configure the system to boot in EFI mode, using rEFInd or [another EFI-mode boot manager and boot loader of your choice.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) If you've got a hybrid MBR, your first step is to convert that to a protective MBR:

1. Launch `gdisk` on the disk, as in `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`.
2. Type `p` to view the partition table.
3. Type `x` to enter the experts' menu.
4. Type `n` to create a fresh protective MBR, wiping out the hybrid MBR.
5. Type `p` to view the partition table. Compare that to the earlier view. You shouldn't need to compare every character of output; the point is to spot accidents like accidentally trashing all your partitions with a typo before you commit your changes to disk.
6. Type `w` to save your changes.

With that done, you have to re-install rEFInd or restore it to bootability. You *might* be able to get this done by installing the [rEFInd PPA or Debian package](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) in the normal (Linux) way; however, Macs are a bit weird, so this might not work. I've even heard of Mac firmware being damaged by Linux tools, but I haven't heard substantiated cases of this in at least two years, so I think the relevant bugs have been fixed. If you try it this way, mount your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) at `/boot/efi` first.

Another way to install rEFInd is to boot an OS X emergency system (such as an OS X install disc), launch an OS X Terminal window (there's an option for that in the menu bar, once it appears), and run rEFInd's `install.sh` from that environment. This *should* work even without re-installing OS X, but I've never verified this.

### Option #2: BIOS-mode booting

As a general rule, if you remove OS X from a Mac, it's generally easier to manage the OS(es) on that computer using the Mac's Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which enables BIOS-mode booting. To do this, you should convert the disk from GPT to MBR (full-on regular MBR, not hybrid MBR). This procedure is described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) You'll have to reboot after this conversion, but your Linux installation will no longer be bootable, so be prepared with an Ubuntu live image.

Once the disk is converted, you'll need to install a BIOS-mode boot loader. The simplest way to do this is probably to run [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) You must be careful, though, to run Boot Repair from a BIOS-mode boot of an emergency disc. You can verify a BIOS-mode boot by looking for a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`; if it's present, you've booted in EFI mode, and if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS mode. If you boot your emergency system in EFI mode, try using the Option or Alt key when you reboot to boot the medium in another way. In an extreme case, prepare a USB flash drive emergency disk and remove the `EFI` directory tree from the FAT partition on that disk. This should render it unbootable in EFI mode.

As you're currently booting in EFI mode (at least as far as rEFInd), even if a bit strangely, converting to a strictly BIOS-mode boot carries some risk that you'll make matters worse. It should work, but in an (almost) worst-case scenario, you might have to try various repair utilities until something "clicks."